# Bash: Read file that contains a star (*)

Tags: bash

I'm to read the contents of a file in a variable. Doing the following is great:

```
content1=$(<content-1.html)
```

However, if that file contains a star (*), instead of reading it properly, it replaces it with the list of files in the working directory.

So, if the file contains the following:

```
var randomFirst = (Math.floor( Math.random() * (items.length) ) );
```

Reading it turns it into the following:

```
 var randomFirst = (Math.floor( Math.random() backups compile.sh content css favicon.ico img libs output template.html template_compiled.html (items.length) ) );
```

How should I read the file to make sure special characters are not interpreted?

Thanks,

Comment: How about `content1=$(cat content-1.html)`?

Comment: It's very bad habit to use a * in a filename and you should try to avoid it at all times. If you're using special characters in names, you have to use an escape character to escape its meaning in bash. This is char is '\'.

Comment: Hello @Jakke, thanks for your comment. I may have wrongly explained my situation, the star is actually within the file (it's a javascript file).

Comment: Hello @OliverSalzburg, thanks for your suggestion. Still behaved the same though!

Answer (score 3):

The simple answer is to use double-quotes:-

```
content1="$(<content-1.html)"
echo "$content1"
```

Double-quotes allow the expansion of variables, but not of file masks. The quotes do not appear in the expansion. So always use double-quotes when referencing **content1**.

In fact, the first statement does not strictly need the double-quotes, as **bash** does not rescan an input line, but they do no harm.

So your problem is not with reading the file, but with how you use its contents.